# Where is Kafka Java API?

Tags: apache-kafka

I’m trying to use some Kafka API with Kafka 1.0 and I find myself baffled at a fundamental level.

There’s a class [`AdminClient`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html) that’s been around since 0.10 or so. It has a method `describeTopics` I want to try. So I set up an Eclipse project and construct an `AdminClient` and point it to my Kafka cluster and all is well.

Until I examine the `AdminClient` class a little more closely and find it is a Scala module and quite different from the published Java API. Among other things `describeTopics` is nowhere to be found.

So I downloaded *Kafka-1.0.0-src.tgz* asnd poked around. I found *core/src/main/scala/admin/AdminClient.scala* which matches what I saw in Eclipse. Then I found *clients/src/main/java/org/apache/clients/admin/AdminClient.java* which matches the API doc.

I have the feeling there’s something I’m missing. How can I get to the API I see in the documentation?

Comment: [Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeTopics-java.util.Collection-) -> [Source](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/078fd2136524409711e535544ac8960135064df3/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.java#L179).

Comment: Can you share your pom file, or whatever you added in dependencies?
Your only dependency should be on org.apache.kafka.clients and org.apache.kafka.common, so you shouldn't see anything in the core module at all. Core module isn't the client - it is the broker itself!

Answer (score 0):

It’s right here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.java, which is in the `kafka-clients` artifact: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.kafka%7Ckafka-clients%7C1.0.0%7Cjar

Answer (score 0):

The AdminClient you are seeing comes from the core Kafka artifact. The new AdminClient API is available in the Kafka clients library (with consumer and producer) so you should use the following dependency in your pom.xml :

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Scala implementation is the server side of the Admin functionality which runs in the Kafka Brokers which are also written in Scala. The java implementation is the client side which should match the docs because it’s the client API that should be documented.